# Flask with Python error when MySQL Select statement

Tags: python, mysql, flask

So the difference between working and not working is the insertion of the SELECT statement below the SELECT address execute() statement from MySQLdb.

**My function:**

```
@app.route('/ask/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def ask():
    #clients come here first
    error = ''
    try:
    c, conn = connection()
    #grab all the clients info
    email = session['email']
    c.execute("SELECT cid FROM clients WHERE email = (%s)", (thwart(email),))
    clientcid = c.fetchone()[0]
    c.execute("SELECT phone FROM clients WHERE email = (%s)", (thwart(email),))
    phone = c.fetchone()[0]
    c.execute("SELECT rating FROM clients WHERE email = (%s)", (thwart(email),))
    rating = c.fetchone()[0]
    c.execute("SELECT first_name FROM cpersonals WHERE cid = (%s)", (clientcid,))
    first_name = c.fetchone()[0]
    c.execute("SELECT last_name FROM cpersonals WHERE cid = (%s)", (clientcid,))
    last_name = c.fetchone()[0]
    c.execute("SELECT address FROM cpersonals WHERE cid = (%s)", (clientcid,))
    address = c.fetchone()[0]
    c.execute("SELECT zip FROM cpersonals WHERE cid = (%s)", (clientcid,))
    czip = c.fetchone()[0]
    c.execute("SELECT reg_date FROM cpersonals WHERE cid = (%s)", (clientcid,))
    reg_date = c.fetchone()[0]
    conn.commit()
    c.close()
    conn.close()


    session['logged_in'] = 'client'
    session['clientcid'] = clientcid
    session['phone'] = phone
    session['rating'] = rating
    session['first_name'] = first_name
    session['last_name'] = last_name
    session['address'] = address
    session['czip'] = czip
    session['reg_date'] = reg_date

    #if user posts a question to the pool
        if request.method == 'POST':
            #grab question info from form
            difficulty = request.form['difficulty']
            title = request.form['title']
            body = request.form['body']
            clientcid = session['clientcid']
            c, conn = connection()

            c.execute("INSERT INTO tickets (cid, difficulty, title, body) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)", (clientcid, difficulty, thwart(title), thwart(body)))
            conn.commit()
            c.close()
            conn.close()

            flash("Submission successful.")
            return redirect(url_for('ask'))

        else:
            error = "We couldn't post your question, please reload the page and try again!"

        return render_template("ask.html")

    except Exception as e:
        return(str(e))
```

**Inserting this just below the `SELECT address FROM cpersonals`:**

```
c.execute("SELECT city FROM cpersonals WHERE cid = (%s)", (clientcid,))
city = c.fetchone()[0]
```

Super confused because this is the same as the SELECT statement above them for getting the address, yet it causes a 500 error. Anyone have a clue on what areas I can look at to solve this? Why would it be behaving as such?

EDIT:
**Apache error log:**

```
[Tue Nov 14 03:20:26.932754 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 10241:tid 140272413560320] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Nov 14 03:20:27.002887 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 10347:tid 140399854022144] AH00489: Apache/2.4.25 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.5.11 Python/2.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Nov 14 03:20:27.003054 2017] [core:notice] [pid 10347:tid 140399854022144] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Nov 14 03:20:28.212299 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 10351:tid 140399645546240] [client 108.196.200.128:64860] mod_wsgi (pid=10351): Target WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module., referer: http://138.197.210.172/login/
[Tue Nov 14 03:20:28.212379 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 10351:tid 140399645546240] [client 108.196.200.128:64860] mod_wsgi (pid=10351): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi'., referer: http://138.197.210.172/login/
[Tue Nov 14 03:20:28.212415 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 10351:tid 140399645546240] [client 108.196.200.128:64860] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://138.197.210.172/login/
[Tue Nov 14 03:20:28.212451 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 10351:tid 140399645546240] [client 108.196.200.128:64860]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi", line 7, in <module>, referer: http://138.197.210.172/login/
[Tue Nov 14 03:20:28.212558 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 10351:tid 140399645546240] [client 108.196.200.128:64860]     from FlaskApp import app as application, referer: http://138.197.210.172/login/
[Tue Nov 14 03:20:28.212622 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 10351:tid 140399645546240] [client 108.196.200.128:64860]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/__init__.py", line 41, referer: http://138.197.210.172/login/
[Tue Nov 14 03:20:28.212635 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 10351:tid 140399645546240] [client 108.196.200.128:64860]     c.execute("SELECT state FROM cpersonals WHERE cid = (%s)", (clientcid,)), referer: http://138.197.210.172/login/
[Tue Nov 14 03:20:28.212641 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 10351:tid 140399645546240] [client 108.196.200.128:64860]     ^, referer: http://138.197.210.172/login/
[Tue Nov 14 03:20:28.212647 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 10351:tid 140399645546240] [client 108.196.200.128:64860] SyntaxError: invalid syntax, referer: http://138.197.210.172/login/
[Tue Nov 14 03:20:28.269478 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 10350:tid 140399578404608] [client 108.196.200.128:64861] mod_wsgi (pid=10350): Target WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module., referer: http://138.197.210.172/ask/
[Tue Nov 14 03:20:28.269538 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 10350:tid 140399578404608] [client 108.196.200.128:64861] mod_wsgi (pid=10350): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi'., referer: http://138.197.210.172/ask/
[Tue Nov 14 03:20:28.269566 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 10350:tid 140399578404608] [client 108.196.200.128:64861] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://138.197.210.172/ask/
[Tue Nov 14 03:20:28.269594 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 10350:tid 140399578404608] [client 108.196.200.128:64861]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi", line 7, in <module>, referer: http://138.197.210.172/ask/
[Tue Nov 14 03:20:28.269679 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 10350:tid 140399578404608] [client 108.196.200.128:64861]     from FlaskApp import app as application, referer: http://138.197.210.172/ask/
[Tue Nov 14 03:20:28.269730 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 10350:tid 140399578404608] [client 108.196.200.128:64861]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/__init__.py", line 41, referer: http://138.197.210.172/ask/
[Tue Nov 14 03:20:28.269740 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 10350:tid 140399578404608] [client 108.196.200.128:64861]     c.execute("SELECT state FROM cpersonals WHERE cid = (%s)", (clientcid,)), referer: http://138.197.210.172/ask/
[Tue Nov 14 03:20:28.269747 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 10350:tid 140399578404608] [client 108.196.200.128:64861]     ^, referer: http://138.197.210.172/ask/
[Tue Nov 14 03:20:28.269753 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 10350:tid 140399578404608] [client 108.196.200.128:64861] SyntaxError: invalid syntax, referer: http://138.197.210.172/ask/
```

Comment: Do you get a stack trace when the 500 occurs?

Comment: @MrName sorry, not familiar with stack trace, how would I go about that?

Comment: It would be in the logs of your application.

Comment: @MrName the Apache logs give the error: `File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/__init__.py", line 41, referer: http://138.197.210.172/ask/` ----- `c.execute("SELECT state FROM cpersonals WHERE cid = (%s)", (clientcid,)), referer: http://138.197.210.172/ask/` ----- `^, referer: http://138.197.210.172/ask/ SyntaxError: invalid syntax, referer: http://138.197.210.172/ask/`

Comment: Which isnt too helpful, I looked around for other error logs, but couldn't find any

Comment: What is the "strange error" you are getting?

Comment: @kstullich Error as observed: why when adding the same lines of a code but with just changed variables, does it throw an error?

Comment: That looks like the web server error log. Do you have application error log?

Comment: Like @MrName said, please show the application error you are getting.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/where-is-my-flask-error-log-located      Says that the flask error log should be redirected to the apache log. A bit lost on that as well, where do I find the proper error log? Do I have to specify this for Flask? @MrName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: all I needed to do was tab out the statements below the `try` statement. I suppose this is because Python is very finicky about tabbing!

**As such:**

```
try:
        c, conn = connection()
        #grab all the clients info
        email = session['email']
        c.execute("SELECT cid FROM clients WHERE email = (%s)", (thwart(email),))
        clientcid = c.fetchone()[0]
        c.execute("SELECT phone FROM clients WHERE email = (%s)", (thwart(email),))
        phone = c.fetchone()[0]
        c.execute("SELECT rating FROM clients WHERE email = (%s)", (thwart(email),))
        rating = c.fetchone()[0]
        c.execute("SELECT first_name FROM cpersonals WHERE cid = (%s)", (clientcid,))
        first_name = c.fetchone()[0]
        c.execute("SELECT last_name FROM cpersonals WHERE cid = (%s)", (clientcid,))
        last_name = c.fetchone()[0]
        c.execute("SELECT address FROM cpersonals WHERE cid = (%s)", (clientcid,))
        address = c.fetchone()[0]
        c.execute("SELECT city FROM cpersonals WHERE cid = (%s)", (clientcid,))
        city = c.fetchone()[0]
        c.execute("SELECT state FROM cpersonals WHERE cid = (%s)", (clientcid,))
        state = c.fetchone()[0]
        c.execute("SELECT zip FROM cpersonals WHERE cid = (%s)", (clientcid,))
        czip = c.fetchone()[0]
        c.execute("SELECT reg_date FROM cpersonals WHERE cid = (%s)", (clientcid,))
        reg_date = c.fetchone()[0]
        conn.commit()
        c.close()
        conn.close()


        session['logged_in'] = 'client'
        session['clientcid'] = clientcid
        session['phone'] = phone
        session['rating'] = rating
        session['first_name'] = first_name
        session['last_name'] = last_name
        session['address'] = address
        session['city'] = city
        session['state'] = state
        session['czip'] = czip
        session['reg_date'] = reg_date

       #if user posts a question to the pool
        if request.method == 'POST':
            #grab question info from form
            difficulty = request.form['difficulty']
            title = request.form['title']
            body = request.form['body']
            clientcid = session['clientcid']
            c, conn = connection()
```